# Error 508 Invalid data in MERCHANT_ID field. Please contact the merchant

Tags: javascript, python, django, global-payments-api

Can anyone help me understand why do I get this error? I used the merchant_id that I was given at https://developer.globalpay.com/

```
<<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("sdkRequestEndpoint", function(jsonFromRequestEndpoint) {
        RealexHpp.setHppUrl("https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay");
        RealexHpp.lightbox.init("payButtonId", "responseEndpoint", jsonFromRequestEndpoint);
      });
    });
</script>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Add these links in the head section of your HTML file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <h2>Make a Booking</h2>
    <form action="https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay" method="POST" target="iframe">
  <input type="hidden" name="TIMESTAMP" value="20180613110737">
  <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_ID" value="MER_7e3e2c7df34f42819b3edee31022ee3f">  //my Merchant_ID
  <input type="hidden" name="ACCOUNT" value="internet">
  <input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID" value="N6qsk4kYRZihmPrTXWYS6g">
  <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="1999">
  <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_SETTLE_FLAG" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="COMMENT1" value="Mobile Channel">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_VERSION" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CHANNEL" value="ECOM">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_LANG" value="en">
  <!-- Begin 3D Secure 2 Mandatory and Recommended Fields -->
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CUSTOMER_EMAIL" value="test@example.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CUSTOMER_PHONENUMBER_MOBILE" value="44|789456123">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_BILLING_STREET1" value="Flat 123">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_BILLING_STREET2" value="House 456">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_BILLING_STREET3" value="Unit 4">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_BILLING_CITY" value="Halifax">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_BILLING_POSTALCODE" value="W5 9HR">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_BILLING_COUNTRY" value="826">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_SHIPPING_STREET1" value="Apartment 852">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_SHIPPING_STREET2" value="Complex 741">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_SHIPPING_STREET3" value="House 963">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_SHIPPING_CITY" value="Chicago">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_SHIPPING_STATE" value="IL">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_SHIPPING_POSTALCODE" value="50001">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_SHIPPING_COUNTRY" value="840">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_ADDRESS_MATCH_INDICATOR" value="FALSE">
  <input type="hidden" name="HPP_CHALLENGE_REQUEST_INDICATOR" value="NO_PREFERENCE">
  <!-- End 3D Secure 2 Mandatory and Recommended Fields -->
  <!-- Begin Fraud Management and Reconciliation Fields -->
  <input type="hidden" name="BILLING_CODE" value="59|123">
  <input type="hidden" name="BILLING_CO" value="GB">
  <input type="hidden" name="SHIPPING_CODE" value="50001|Apartment 852">
  <input type="hidden" name="SHIPPING_CO" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="CUST_NUM" value="6e027928-c477-4689-a45f-4e138a1f208a">
  <input type="hidden" name="VAR_REF" value="Acme Corporation">
  <input type="hidden" name="PROD_ID" value="SKU1000054">
  <!-- End Fraud Management and Reconciliation Fields -->
  <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANT_RESPONSE_URL" value="https://www.example.com/responseUrl">
  <input type="hidden" name="CARD_PAYMENT_BUTTON" value="Pay Invoice">
  <input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME" value="Custom Field Data">
  <input type="hidden" name="SHA1HASH" value="308bb8dfbbfcc67c28d602d988ab104c3b08d012">
  <input type="submit" value="Click To Pay">
</form>
    


<script>
                     
        // configure client, request and HPP settings
GatewayConfig config = new GatewayConfig();
config.setMerchantId("MER_7e3e2c7df34f42819b3edee31022ee3f"); //my Merchant_ID
config.setAccountId("internet");
config.setSharedSecret("xxxxxxxxxxx");   //my app key
config.setServiceUrl("https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay");

HostedPaymentConfig hostedPaymentConfig = new HostedPaymentConfig();
hostedPaymentConfig.setVersion(HppVersion.Version2);
config.setHostedPaymentConfig(hostedPaymentConfig);

// Add 3D Secure 2 Mandatory and Recommended Fields
HostedPaymentData hostedPaymentData = new HostedPaymentData();
hostedPaymentData.setCustomerEmail("james.mason@example.com");
hostedPaymentData.setCustomerPhoneMobile("44|07123456789");
hostedPaymentData.setAddressesMatch(false);

Address billingAddress = new Address();
billingAddress.setStreetAddress1("Flat 123");
billingAddress.setStreetAddress2("House 456");
billingAddress.setStreetAddress3("Unit 4");
billingAddress.setCity("Halifax");
billingAddress.setPostalCode("W5 9HR");
billingAddress.setCountry("826");

Address shippingAddress = new Address();
shippingAddress.setStreetAddress1("Apartment 825");
shippingAddress.setStreetAddress2("Complex 741");
shippingAddress.setStreetAddress3("House 963");
shippingAddress.setCity("Chicago");
shippingAddress.setState("IL");
shippingAddress.setPostalCode("50001");
shippingAddress.setCountry("840");
        
HostedService service = new HostedService(config);

try {
    String hppJson = service.charge(new BigDecimal("19.99"))
    .withCurrency("EUR")
    .withHostedPaymentData(hostedPaymentData)
    .withAddress(billingAddress, AddressType.Billing)
    .withAddress(shippingAddress, AddressType.Shipping)
    .serialize();
    // TODO: pass the HPP request JSON to the JavaScript, iOS or Android Library
} catch (ApiException exce) {
    // TODO: Add your error handling here
}
    </script>
```

I was trying to test the payment system with the example code and got an error after clicking the -Click To Pay- button. if anyone have a django project that has the global payments service installed it will be very helpfull. thanks!